# ANN regression accuracy and loss stuck

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

I have a data set on predicting solar power generation,the dataset has 20 independent var and 1 dependent. The accuracy of my model is stuck at 60%. I have tried several models but this accuracy is best I could get other sucks even more.
Here is my code:

```
data_path = r'drive/My Drive/Proj/S.P.F./solarpowergeneration.csv'
dts = pd.read_csv('solarpowergeneration.csv')
dts.head()
X = dts.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dts.iloc[:, -1].values
print(X.shape, y.shape)
y = np.reshape(y, (-1,1))
y.shape
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc= StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
y_train = sc.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = sc.transform(y_test)

import keras.backend as K  
def calc_accu(y_true, y_pred):
  return K.mean(K.equal(K.round(y_true), K.round(y_pred)))

def get_spfnet():
  ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

  ann.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
# ann.add(BatchNormalization())
  ann.add(Dropout(0.3))
  ann.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
 # ann.add(BatchNormalization())
  ann.add(Dropout(0.3))
  ann.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
 # ann.add(BatchNormalization())
  ann.add(Dropout(0.3))

  ann.add(Dense(1))
  ann.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(), calc_accu])
  return ann

spfnet = get_spfnet()
#spfnet.summary()
hist = spfnet.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=250, verbose=2)
```

the accuracy and loss graphs are

```
plt.plot(hist.history['calc_accu'])
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()
plt.plot(hist.history['root_mean_squared_error'])
plt.title('Model error')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('error')
plt.show()
```

[image]    [image]

after 50 epochs nothing seems to improve, neither curve seems to overfit on the data
I tried other models like reducing layers and removing kernel regularizes, using

```
kernel_initlizers='normal' and 'he-normal'
```

but they perform poorly stuck at 20%.

dataset:
[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause is a gradient near zero. You may be stuck at local minima or saddle point. Pls try increasing `batch_size` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential/#evaluate)

Comment: i tried increasing batch size to 128 and 256 but got similar results,

Comment: Your model appears to be under fitting.. You may have a data set that is to small to extract all the features. How many training samples do you have?

Comment: ITS around 2500